# Window 7 can't see outside gateway when connecting via Ubiquity wireless access point

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I just installed a Ubiquity Unifi Pro wireless access point.

Access is uneventful from machines running XP and SuSE Linux. Win 7 however connects OK but cannot see outside the gateway. I have tried access with several computers running Win 7 with the same unsuccessful result.  I've attempted both static and DHCP settings.  Any Ideas ??

I am able to connect to the WAP and ping any device on the LAN but not the WAN. Previously I was using a Linksys router as a WAP. The range was inadequate so I plan to replace it with the Unifi WAP which has a significantly greater range and can ultimately be set up for roaming. The thing that really puzzles me is that XP and Linux access is OK

IP: 192.168.1.149
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS: 192.168.1.1

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_Win 7 connects OK but cannot see outside the gateway._"?  Does this mean you ARE able to ping across your LAN to your other computers, but not out to the Internet (or WAN)?  Are your Win 7 computers able to successfully connect to any other wireless access point?  Please update your question with this clarifying information.

Comment: I am able to connect to the WAP and ping any device on the LAN but not the WAN.  Previously I was using a Linksys router as a WAP.  The range was inadequate so I plan to replace it with the Unifi WAP which has a significantly greater range and can ultimately be set up for roaming.  The thing that really puzzles me is that XP and Linux access is OK.

Comment: If you can ping on the LAN, then this isn't a wifi problem.  Do you get different results when connected via Ethernet?  It sounds like either a firewall or a DNS problem.  Can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: When connecting using a wired connection everything behaves normally.  I thought it might be a DNS issue but I can't ping 8.8.8.8 or anything outside the local network.  What this tells me is that it doesn't understand that 192.168.1.1 is the gateway and thus can't find its way out of the local network.